# TSQL Count Case When In

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble with some logic here. Trying to get a count of rows where S.ID's not in my subquery.

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN S.ID IN
(SELECT DISTINCT S.ID FROM...) 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

I am recieving the error:

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

How to fix this or an alternative?

Comment: Please show the complete query.

Comment: DISTINCT don't do anything here and I guess you meant to use SUM not COUNT.

Comment: @adrianm yes, that doesn't help does it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM .... WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT COUNT(t.*) FROM table1 t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ID = t.ID)
```

Comment: If table2 is empty, this returns 0. If table2 is not empty it returns the count of all rows in table1. (hint: you need WHERE clause in exists)

Answer (score 1):

Use following construct with CTE.

```
  with cte as 
  (
  select 
    case
     when S.ID in (SELECT DISTINCT S.ID FROM LookupTable) then 1
     else 0
    end
    as SID
  from MyTable)
  select count(SID) as SIDCOUNT from cte;
```